# UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the Salesforce

Tags: windows-phone-7, salesforce, service-reference

In windows Phone application, i added Enterprise.wsdl(obtained from my salesforce login id) as reference. I'm able to authenticate using Loginresult. But while using Create the above expense are thrown.

Using SoapHeader class in Web application inherited System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader  so referred the Server url  and id.
It is not possible to use web in Windows phone. Plz help if you know any samples to solve it

Comment: I checked login authentication of salesforce in windows phone. working correctly.If i want to insert records in customized table of salesforce,must appended server url,id of my login.In .net using   SessionHeader class used for passing id and url to salesforce.In   WindowsPhone which is the Class Equivalent to SessionHeader class? Help me to implement if you know

Answer (score 2):

Part of the results for the login call are a serverUrl, this url should be used to make all subsequent requests, typically in .NET you just set the .Url property of your stub to the provided value. While there are no win-phone specific examples, there are lots of .NET examples in the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that you can't import the Partner or Enterprise WSDLs to a Windows Phone 7 project.

With Windows Phone 7 projects you can add a Service Reference (for WCF), but not a Web Reference.

Whenever I've imported the Salesforce WSDLs to a standard .NET project I've needed to use a Web Reference to get the APIs working correctly. Something about how WCF doesn't support the Salesforce WSDL defined SOAP headers that are needed to specify the session details.

I found using the [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) and [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to be the easiest with Windows Phone 7 projects.

That said, my phone app only works with Developer, Enterprise and Unlimited Salesforce editions. Professional and Group editions get the API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG error. I think I need to get the app certified to work with those editions.